# Can one change the rules of this site?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to change the rules of this site?
I have some ideas as to how to improve this website and wanted to know whether I can make any contributions to the way the site operates.

Comment: I didn't see you come back, but really - what are some of your ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. We are able to change some aspects of this site as long as they adhere to the basic goals outlined for this site as it was created, and as long as they conform to StackExchange's philosophies in how they want their Q&A sites to be formatted.

So for example we can modify the kind of questions we accept in the Q&A format, how strict we need to be with citing/referencing, how much *original research* is acceptible, etc., but we can't turn this site into a forum. Questions need to be questions, and they need to have real answers.

If you have an idea, by all means share it with us here. We will tell you on a case by case basis whether it is allowed or feasible, and other members of the community can chime in as well on how they feel about it.

Comment: Here's one idea: if questions can be put on hold or closed on a quality basis, there must be a rule that after editing (either by the author or anybody else) to a sufficient extent (or else deletion by the author), the question must be reopened.

Comment: The problem is that such a rule ("auto-reopening after X amount of change") would defeat the purpose of editing, which is to improve the question. If a question has been edited by X% but ***is still not a good question***, it shouldn't automatically be reopened, right?

Comment: I do not mean to automatically reopen. I mean that there should be a rule that a question should be edited until the community agrees that it is fit to reopen.

Comment: Then how is that different from what we do now?

Comment: Now, it is very easy for a group of users to simply close or put on hold a question and not return to it (even if the author has made edits).

Comment: Can you think of what kind of change you are asking for and spell it out in detail in a separate answer to this question? Try as I can, I cannot see any way of implementing what you desire that is possible for us.

Comment: I also have an idea. I think when it comes to philosophy having a restriction as to how long a comment can be is very counter productive. Say someone answers a question about a concept. And someone notices that there are some fundamental mistakes in the answer, the best thing to do is to point it out in a comment. Especially in philosophy that can require quite lengthly explanation. So one would have to post it as an answer. But it's not necessarily an answer, but rather pointing out why another answer isn't actually an answer. That would be most appropriate in comment- rather than answer-form

Comment: We can't change comment length limits, that'd have to be done by the admins. We are however supposed to try to push lengthy comment discussions to chat, but we are pretty lenient with that. Philosophy often does require a bit more discussion than other disciplines before ideas can be communicated properly.